# How to make border radius closer to the center

Tags: html, css

I want to make a shadow around a rounded image, to do so I used a `border-radius: 100px` and a `box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;` to it, but I want to make it deeper to reach the circle and remove that white part.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like.

```css
.bubbles {
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
}
```

```html
<a href=""><img class="bubbles" src="https://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_771288logomesure.png" alt="Heberger image" /></a>
```

[image: screenshot]

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pqfo5g5f/)

Comment: Provide working snippet

Comment: I edited it ;-)

Comment: inset shadow ? https://jsfiddle.net/pqfo5g5f/1/ or both outset/inset ? https://jsfiddle.net/pqfo5g5f/2/ or background https://jsfiddle.net/pqfo5g5f/3/ ... or a mix of these

Comment: I want the shadow to start from the circle, not from the white outline, ty for your answer anyway, didnt know that part of the shadows

Comment: then you might just need background and inset shadow mix https://jsfiddle.net/pqfo5g5f/4/ , otherwise a radial-gradient ....

Comment: thats not exactly what i want :/ just an outside shadow from the border of the rounded image

Comment: here is a fish .... https://jsfiddle.net/pqfo5g5f/5/ .... take the hints, do research , learn and improve yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the image and need a CSS solution. Use a div and set the background-image instead of using an `<img />` tag.

```css
.bubbles {
  width: 147px;
  height: 147px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
  background-image: url('https://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_771288logomesure.png');
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-position: -10px -10px, center;
}
```

```html
<a href=""><div class="bubbles" /></a>
```

Comment: feel free  include the radial gradient from my comment which is also a background-image :)  and requires setting only on the radial https://jsfiddle.net/pqfo5g5f/5/

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the "white part", is this part the white border around the image?

The border is due to the white background of the image you're using. I suggest you directly edit it (using Gimp or Inkscape) to get rid of it. See [How to make a color transparent using Gimp](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36520/how-to-make-a-color-transparent-in-gimp) to get an explanation.

Hope it will help !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The actual image is a png file that only contain the rounded image with transparency around it but css interpret it like a squared image, thats why is used  `border-radius`.
I tried `border-witdh` but it doesn't seems to do the job :/